Free solver for large LP with warm start and shadow prices
Please advise me a free solver for large linear programming problems that

supports warm start
can calculate shadow prices simultaneously solving the LP problem
has Python interface

I considered GLOP (which is used in OR-tools) and HiGHS, but I'm not sure if they can 1 и 2.

What exactly you mean by can calculate shadow prices simultaneously solving the LP problem?

Almost, all of the standard LP/MIP solvers, open-source/commercial, do benefit from the warm-start feature and calculating dual solutions.

Concerning HiGHS, it offers warm starting provided that you use the simplex method to solve the LP. Warm starting interior point solvers is much less efficient.
Any solver is also able to provide dual information. However, notice that dual variables computed by different solvers may differ quite a bit.
